# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'car' is defined

Tags: java, spring

Can anyone tell me what is the error in this program and how to correct the error? I have given proper annotation and still getting errors.
I need help fixing this error I get when trying to deploy . Why isn't the Car bean being defined? Am I missing something in my web.xml or do I have to map the customerService somehow? I am using annotations for mapping. any help would be much appreciated. Here is the error log entry from the localhost log:

App.java

```
package om.venkatesh.omshakthi;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        
        Car obj=(Car)context.getBean("car");
        obj.drive();
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
package om.venkatesh.omshakthi;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Car implements Vehicle{
    
    public void drive()
    {
        System.out.println("Car");
        
    }

}
```

Vehicle.java

```
package om.venkatesh.omshakthi;

public interface Vehicle {
     void drive();

}
```

Spring.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
   <bean id="tyre" class="om.venkatesh.omshakthi.Tyre">
   
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You are using xml, you need to tell that to scan for compoj=onents by adding.`<conext:component-scan base-packages="your package here" />` else it won't scan for components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without xml you can do it like this:

Create config class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Car car() {
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
    ctx.refresh();

    Car car = (Car) ctx.getBean("car");
    car.drive();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring.xml has no bean with id "car" (although there is one for "tyre")

Comment: I have given annotation for Car , right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your bean in XML

```
<bean id="car" class="om.venkatesh.omshakthi.Car">
```

Comment: how to use only annotation without xml

Comment: You do understand that your project is using XML that you shared with us?
If you are not interested in the solution on the code example that you provided please either alter your question or delete it.
Your subquestion is not related to your original question or the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need @Component annotation when you use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.
Just define a Car bean in your xml:

```
<bean id="car" class="om.venkatesh.omshakthi.Car">
```

Comment: how to use only annotation without xml